# Internet Explorer and its shortcomings (no Firebug-like debug tool)

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am using PHP/jQuery and JavaScript. I am testing the JavaScript code in Firefox using [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29). Is there anything similar for Internet Explorer?

I am struggling to get it to look/work the same in Internet Explorer 7 and [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8).

Are there any tools to solve this? Or standards that I need to follow? And also, what debugger can be recommended?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94934/what-debug-logging-tools-are-available-from-javascript

Comment: hope my cleanup helps. If i've got anything wrong, feel free to change it back.

Comment: This should have a more descriptive title!

Comment: @Dana Robinson, are you suggesting IE has more thn one problem?

Comment: Ha!  Anyone who has done Javascript or CSS work knows that IE is the work of Satan.  I still have the dent in my forehead from getting the WMD editor buttons to look right in IE.

Answer (score 11):

Check this out:

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 5):

You can force IE8 to use the same rendering engine as IE7.

Chris Koenig from Microsoft explains it in a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/chkoenig/archive/2008/08/28/ie8-standards-mode-and-ie7-compatibility-mode.aspx)

In terms of debuggers for IE I'd recommend [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/). It's by far the best debugger for IE. While it's not as tightly integrated as Firebug, for raw JS debugging power it's king. You can set break points, step through code, and do all the normal things you'd want from a debugger. It doesn't have the HTML inspection of Firebug but the IE Developer Toolbar can help you there.

Comment: He asked about a tool similar to the firebug :)

Comment: but he is also interested in whether there are any other ways to solve the problem - which maybe was more apparent from the original question.

Comment: It was the "look/work" the same that I figured this was useful.

Answer (score 5):

There is **Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar** which @Paolo Bergantino already mentioned. It is just as useful as Firebug. But another solution could be [**Firebug Lite**](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) which works for Internet Explorer, [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), and [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29).

And a very creative way to implement it via [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) is described in *[Firebug console for IE](http://www.phpied.com/firebug-console-for-ie/)*.

Comment: I've found Firebug Lite to be less than useful in my experience.  IE really needs better tools.

Comment: I can hardly agree that the IE dev toolbar is just as useful as Firebug.  With Firebug you can set breakpoints in JS and observe all the http calls that are happening in the background, and that is just scratching the surface.  Suppose it's the best there is at the moment for IE though.

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer 8 has a debugging toolkit that is very similar to Firebug's.  Just press F12 to bring it up.  Since you can force IE8 to use the IE7 rendering engine you'd be able to debug both of them using it.

Comment: Interesting, how do I force IE8 to use the IE7 rendering engine. Is that the compatibility view feature?

Comment: just insert this meta tag into the head of your documents:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

Comment: IE8's Developer Tool's debugger is actually better than Firebug's. Firebug sometimes loses track of the code that is being executed and it’s not possible to debug crunched files that appear on a single line of code. The debugger in IE8 handles all these issues perfectly because (I assume) it's more tightly integrated with the browser.

Answer (score 1):

For an equivalent to the Firebug net panel, you can use the newly released [MSFast](http://msfast.myspace.com/) from MySpace.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent alternative that I have been using for years is [DebugBar](http://www.my-debugbar.com).

It is:

- More stable than MySpace's [MSFast](http://msfast.myspace.com/)
- Better at most things than Microsoft's [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Tools)
- Far more useful than [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (which is really just a fancy console)
- Much faster than [Ext JS's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) script, and it doesn't crash on [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) testing

There are a number of useful bookmarklets and [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) type scripts, primarily  [XRay](http://www.westciv.com/xray/).

Unfortunately, none of these are even close to Firebug, but then again, they are trying to tame a much more vicious beast.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but the Firebug developers have created [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) for use in other browsers. This is a pure JavaScript solution, so it doesn't rely on anything installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

For versions of Internet Explorer, throw a "debugger" command

```
function MakeInternet(obj)
{
    debugger

    internet = obj;
}
```

in your JavaScript code, and it will let you pick how you want to debug it.